# I have two xcassets in my project. Why cannot load one of the xcassets' picture when run on the device/simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, xcasset

I have tow xcassets in my project:

[image]

and both was copied to the bundle resources.

[image]

And I can see the picture on xib:

[image]

When I run the project, NO picture in the `bjzjicons.xcassets` was shown on the device/simulator.

But if I move the picture in `bjzjicons.xcassets` to `Images.xcassets` , they can show correct.

Can anyone tell me why ?

Comment: It probably attempts to load them from default assets catalogue.

Comment: @Andy  so the XCode does not support multi-xcassets ?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem just by moving the `xcassets` to the same folder with the `xxx.xcodeproj/xcworkspace`.